# Takes 1 row from list in each ID

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me to the SQL Oracle with the showing only 1 row result in each ID group, Order by DATE DESC below:

**From this list**
Table: Employees

```
____________________________
ID | Employees | Date
___+___________+____________
1  | A         | 2017-08-01
1  | A         | 2017-08-08
2  | B         | 2017-07-01
2  | B         | 2017-07-10
2  | B         | 2017-07-05
```

**Result**

```
____________________________
ID | Employees | Date
___+___________+____________
1  | A         | 2017-08-08
2  | B         | 2017-07-10
```

Comment: Will the correspondence between ID and Employees (why the plural?) be exactly one-to-one? In which case one has to wonder why you have both ID and Employees and not just one of them. Or does "Employees" sometimes change for the same ID, and you must pick up the most recent one? If so, your example should reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways of achieving this. It really depends on what business rules you want to use to choose the one date per employee. You haven't specified anything, but your desired output suggests you need the most recent date. If so you can use the `max()` aggregate function with a GROUP BY clause.

```
select id,
        employees,
        max(date) as date
from employee
group by id,
         employees
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytic function :

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

```
select *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Employees ORDER BY date desc) from  Employees
```

then put an outer select to select rank 1

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, emplyoees, max(date) as date1
from employees
group by id, emplyoees;
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Suggest adding a description of what it does and how it answers the question.